# Start/Stop Flow/Endpoint in Mule 3.3.0

Tags: mule

I need to programmatically start or stop a flow or endpoint from another flow. Can this be done? Is there risk of message loss?

```
<flow name="control>
  <vm:inbound-endpoint path="in">
  <script:component>
    <!-- start/stop -->
  </script:component>
</flow>

<flow name="startable-stoppable>
  <any-transport:inbound-endpoint/>
  <component/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research I've found that the best option in my case is to start/stop the connectors associated with the endpoints I want to control.

```
<script:component>
  <script:script engine="groovy">
    muleContext.getRegistry().lookupConnector('connectorName').start() // or stop()
  </script:script>
</script:component>
```

A disadvantage of this approach is that all the endpoints associated with the connector will be affected. If this is a problem, every endpoint should have its own connector.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the lifecycle of Mule moving parts with JMX: use JConsole to find out what MBean you need to access from your scripted component.

Comment: Not sure if this is what I need, seems like your solution filters the message to prevent its processing. In my case the inbound endpoint shouldn't consume messages at all.