# Mule:Customizing AMQP inbound for start and stop consumtion on application events

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

How can i customize AMQP inbound so that it start consumtion only when there exist a row in a database table (using database poller) and stops consumtion of messages on  a bussiness logic. As soon it stops consumtion poller should again start checking for start row in database. So it should be an inbound consuming messages only if a start condition is satisfied and upto the time when end condition is not true. As soon as end consumtion condition hold true it should stop consuming and start checking for start condition in database.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Mule requestor module. This allows you to use an inbound-endpoint mid-flow:https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-module-requester

This way you can have a poll message source to check a db and use the requestor module to request a message via the AMQP transport.

A really rough example to demonstrate the flow:

```
<flow name="test">
   <poll>
      <db:select />
   </poll>
   <expression-filter expression="#[payload != empty]" />
   <mulerequester:request  config-ref="Mule_Requester" resource="amqp://amqp-queue.{queueName}"  doc:name="Mule Requester"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ryan I can consume message in midflow using this module but how can i stop consumtion of message by inbound endpoint on basis of some runtime business condition.

Comment: How can i customize receiver thread poool so that all threads can block and if condition is satisfied it comes out . Is there a way to customize receiver thread pool.

Comment: Do not mess with the thread pool. Instead either stop the flow (http://stackoverflow.com/a/23026279/387927) or the endpoint's connector (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13078649/387927).